# Can someone explain this node setup for rotation?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

This is a node setup used to align twigs with branches:

[image]

I would like to understand what these nodes are doing exactly. I tried studying what Euler nodes are, but I did not understand anything.

Comment: See if [this](https://youtu.be/IQdT5kACMQc) YT explanation helps.

Comment: @Joachim some of his visualizations were wrong where he has pinned his comment and most of his explanation has been about the vector input and not all of them

Comment: Sorry, whose visualizations? Pinned his comment? How exactly does that relate to this question? I'm confused.

Comment: the comment was for the yt you provided